# Converting data to space?

Tags: ida, mips

I made a mistake when trying to import some additional binary data into one of my long-time IDA databases. I unintentionally overwrote some empty RAM space, so I tried reverting it back to "space" by undefining or converting the imported code to data. But no such luck - the regions are now filled with thousands of ".byte 0" lines instead.

The database has a ton of comments and renamed variables/functions and I would rather not start over from scratch just to fix this, so is there any other way I can undo this silly mistake? I'm still pretty new to IDA so I hope a potentially dumb question is forgiven here.

I use IDA 6.1 if that changes anything.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the `.byte 0` lines in their own segment?

Comment: @tmr232 Not exactly. That same segment contains `.space 0xN` lines as well, and some empty arrays. But it contains renamed variables and locations, so I wouldn't want to hide the segment or anything, if that's what you're getting at.

Comment: I was getting at that...

Comment: @tmr232 Hehe... oh well, too bad. Can't find anything about this. :(

Comment: I'ld try contacting @ilfak about it, or drop them a mail maybe.